# Percentage and Set theory related question

Tags: elementary-set-theory, percentages, ratio

So I have come across a question Where it says that among 500 students from a school, 35% play football, 25% play cricket and 20% play neither. So how many students play both the sports?

The answer given in the text book is 200 students. But according to my simple logic if 200 students play both football and cricket then how come 175 (35% of 500) play Football in total?

I have also used the concept of Venn diagram and came up with the below mention diagram. Plus I am not considering that the 35% football players only play football. And the 25% cricket players only play cricket.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The given problem is ill-posed.

Since **35% play football** and **25% play cricket**, then those who play neither can only comprise between 40% ($F$ and $C$ are disjoint) to 65% ($C \subseteq F$) of the students. This contradicts the other given piece of information (**20% play neither**).

Comment: Yes that's also what I was thinking.

Comment: Done brother. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

As ryang says, the information given is contradictory if you interpret "$35\%$ play football" literally, so the question is incorrectly written.

What the writer must have *meant* is "$35\%$ only play football, $25\%$ only play cricket and $20\%$ play neither". In that case there are $100\%-35\%-25\%-20\%$ who play both, and this works out to the intended answer.